# Having user input in C

Tags: c, function

I am having a problem with my C code. See the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30]; // Declaring the string-array
    FILE* fileptr; // Declaring the FILE pointer
    char file[10];
    printf("Please enter the file name : ");
    scanf("%s",file);//Taking a single word input
    fileptr = fopen(file,"w");
    if (fileptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No such file found !");

    }
    puts("Please enter some strings here: ");
    gets(name);  //Line 17
    fputs(name,fileptr);
    printf("\nStrings saved to %s",file);
    fclose(fileptr);

}
```

The problem is in Line 17 I used **gets()** instead of **scanf()** but I don't know if it's right or not. I can't get any user input here using **gets()** or other functions. But I want to have multiple word or line string input and the skips after printing the line 16 & then it prints line 19. It doesn't gives me any chance for the input. What should I do?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: *"I can't get any user input"*. Can you please clarify what that means exactly? Give the exact input, expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: What should I use then to take multiple line user input?

Comment: Never use `gets()` — it isn't safe.  Add a loop to get more than one line of input.  Note that `gets()` removes newlines and `fputs))` doesn't add them.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` left a newline in the input which `gets()` immediately read and discarded and returned an empty string.

Comment: @Rafi Research `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function called `remove_trash` like this

```
void remove_trash(void)
{
    char trash[81];
    fgets(trash, 80, stdin);
}
```

Call it before doing `gets(name) //Line 17.`

Answer (score 0):

You would use `scanf` to read formatted input, but needs to be used carefully not to cause a buffer overflow. To safely read strings you would need to use `fgets`, to read from the `stdin` defining a threshold.

As specified on the manpage:

```
char *fgets(char *restrict s, int size, FILE *restrict stream);

// fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
// and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after
// an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
// A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the
// buffer.
```

Comment: I used `fgets()` but it was not working either. I used `scanf()`but wanted more control on the string input.